# Confirm delete dialog using ajax and bootstrap

Tags: ajax, symfony, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to display a **confirm delete dialog** using Bootstrap v3 before deleting an entity.
My code works fine, but without confirm dialog. How can I do that?

```
{% for travel in pagination %}
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4" id="item-{{ travel.id }}">
 //......
        <a title="delete" href data-entity-id="{{ travel.id }}" class="button btn-mini red remove_item">Delete</a>
                  
    </div>
{% endfor %}

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(".remove_item").click(function () {

            var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');
            var itemId = 'item-' + entityId;

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: Routing.generate('travel_delete', {'id': entityId}),
                success: function () {
                    //hide the block of item after delete success
                    $('#' + itemId).fadeOut();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

**Edited**

I tried this code. I'd like when clicking on delete link, pass the value of attr **entity-id** which is in the delete link, to the attr **data-entity-id** in delete button in the modal. How can I do that ?

error console:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

```
<a title="delete" href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" entity-id="{{ travel.id }}" class="button btn-mini uppercase red">Sup ajax</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button data-entity-id="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary remove_item">Delete</button>

</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
            var entityId = $(this).attr('entity-id');
            // set new value of attr data-entity-id but doesn't work
            $('.remove_item').attr('data-entity-id', entityId);

        });

        $(".remove_item").click(function () {
            var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');
            var itemId = 'item-' + entityId;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: Routing.generate('frontend_travel_delete_favorite', {'id': entityId}),
                success: function () {
                    $('#' + itemId).fadeOut();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you ever tried anything?

Comment: yes , but I didn't understand how to pass the entity-id to the button in the modal when clicking on the link "delete" which contains the entity-id

Comment: @Pazi ツ : I have edited my question and have added some code

Comment: Can you show us the the action please as well? I am thinking that `404` is returned because of nonexistent entity (you most probably use `ParamConverter` to resolve `id` => `Object)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this:

```
<a id="delete-btn" title="delete" href data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-entity-id="{{ travel.id }}" class="button btn-mini uppercase red">Sup ajax</a>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
   <button data-entity-id="" type="button" class="btn btn-primary remove_item">Delete</button>

</div>


<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#delete-btn').on('click', function () {
            var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');
            $('.remove_item').attr('data-entity-id', entityId);
        });

        $(".remove_item").click(function () {
            var entityId = $(this).attr('data-entity-id');
            var itemId = 'item-' + entityId;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: Routing.generate('frontend_travel_delete_favorite', {'id': entityId}),
                success: function () {
                    $('#' + itemId).fadeOut();
                }
            });
            return false;
        });


    });
</script>
```